# Table cell combobox - action not performed

Tags: javafx, combobox, tablecell

I'm applying the below cell factory to a column.

```
    targetEnviroment.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DevWorkTabBench, String>, TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String>>() {

                @Override
                public TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String> call(TableColumn<DevWorkTabBench, String> param) {
                    TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String> cell = new TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);

                            String status = null;
                            try {
                                status = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).getObjectStatus();
                            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                            status = "";
                            }
                            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ReadyForDeployment")) {

                                ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox(environmentList);
                                comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                                        commitEdit(newValue);
                                    }
                                });

                                comboBox.setOnShown(new EventHandler<Event>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handle(Event event) {
                                        getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(getIndex());

                                    }
                                });
                                comboBox.setValue(item);
                                setGraphic(comboBox);
                            } else {
                                setGraphic(null);
                            }

                            if (empty) {
                                setGraphic(null);

                            }
                        }
                    };

                    return cell;
                }

            });
```

When I change the `status` to the mentioned status, I get the look of `ComboBox` in that particular cell but the drop down does not occur. Even after multiple clicks no action seems to be performed on the `combobox`. I do not get any exception other than the handled one. Other columns are editable and performing task as expected.

I have no idea what is wrong here. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are always displaying the combo box in the (non-empty) cells, you don't really need to go into "editing" mode as the standard `TextFieldTableCell` etc does. Your implementation is more similar to the `CheckBoxTableCell`, which essentially bypasses the editing mechanism. From the [documentation for that class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html):

> Note that the CheckBoxTableCell renders the CheckBox 'live', meaning
>   that the CheckBox is always interactive and can be directly toggled by
>   the user. This means that it is not necessary that the cell enter its
>   editing state (usually by the user double-clicking on the cell). A
>   side-effect of this is that the usual editing callbacks (such as on
>   edit commit) will not be called. If you want to be notified of
>   changes, it is recommended to directly observe the boolean properties
>   that are manipulated by the CheckBox.

So your cell implementation behaves similarly: don't invoke `edit(...)` (which I think is messing things up) and don't rely on the `commitEdit(...)`, `cancelEdit()` etc methods (which won't work as you're not in editing state), but just update the model class directly.

I can't test, since there isn't a MCVE to work from, so this might not work directly, but it should be enough to get you started toward something that will work.

```
targetEnviroment.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DevWorkTabBench, String>, TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String>>() {

    @Override
    public TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String> call(TableColumn<DevWorkTabBench, String> param) {
        TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String> cell = new TableCell<DevWorkTabBench, String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null) ;
                } else {
                    String status = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).getObjectStatus();

                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ReadyForDeployment")) {

                        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox(environmentList);
                        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                                //commitEdit(newValue);
                                getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).setObjectStatus(newValue);
                            }
                        });

                        comboBox.setValue(item);
                        setGraphic(comboBox);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return cell;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you @James_D . It fixed my problem. But I still cannot understand why making the cell editable messed it up. I'm using the same logic at other places also(like in a `treetableview`).Also the same piece of code is working in one system but at any other place. There the same logic is giving the desired output but not here. How can it give two different results?

Comment: My guess is that calling `edit()` results in `updateItem()` being called. So then you replace the graphic with a new combo box (whose popup isn't displayed). I.e. as soon as the user causes the popup to appear, you replace the combo box. That is a guess though... The lesson from the implementation of `CheckBoxTableCell` seems to be that for "live" editing cells, i.e. cells where the graphic is always displayed (which I think is more appropriate with combo boxes), you shouldn't go in and out of editing state at all.

Comment: You could perhaps experiment with logic in `updateItem()` like `if (isEditing()) { comboBox.show();}`, but it seems a very fragile way to go.

Comment: Your guess seems reasonable as that's exactly whats happening in my case. Though it's still not clear why sometimes it behaves differently in different places.