# How to create javaFx TableColumn with ChoiceBox in each cell, which are always shown, not only in editing mode

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

How can I generate a TableColumn where Choiceboxes are the cell entries. 
I have tried

```
_tableCol.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(choices))
```

After that, a ChoiceBox is only shown when I click on the cell in the table.(I think when the cell is in "editing mode"...so when the cell returns editing=true). I set up the table editable and the column.

What I want is that inside that column, the choice boxes are always visible. Not only the selected value. If nothing is selected than I'll insert a default value, that is not a problem.

I searched a lot and have not found something useful.

Comment: Related question using a `ComboBox`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450297/table-cell-combobox-action-not-performed/36451170#36451170

Comment: thx u really helped me out!